# calculated member first order date - mondrian mdx

Tags: mdx, mondrian

I have a schema with customers, orders and order dates.
A customer can have orders in multiple dates. I need a calculated member to bring the first order date for each client.I tried this but with no success:

```
BottomCount([DATE].[DATE].Members, 1, [DATE].CurrentMember.MemberValue)
```

Comment: I tryed this http://www.purplefrogsystems.com/blog/2012/09/find-first-order-date-in-mdx/ but I get the same date for all my clients which is not correct...Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it with the following:WITH MEMBER [Measures].[MinDate] AS FILTER([Date].[Date].Members, [Date].[Date].CurrentMember > 0).ITEM(0).NAME

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might help

```
 Head
  (EXISTING
   Nonempty
   ( [Date].[Date].members
    ,[Measures].[SomeMeasureInConnectionWithSales]
   )
  ).Item(0)
```

You can then extend this to find out the size of the measure on that date:

```
(
 [Measures].[Total],
 Head
  (EXISTING
   Nonempty
   ( [Date].[Date].members
    ,[Measures].[SomeMeasureInConnectionWithSales]
   )
  ).Item(0)
)
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'm using mondrian mdx, which doesn't support EXISTING function; in this case, if I use Head
   ( [Date].[Date].members
    ,[Measures].[SomeMeasureInConnectionWithSales]
  ).Item(0).NAME, I get the same date for all my clients which is not correct